# Getting the GMarkers that have been added to a Google map?

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way to get a list of all the GMarkers that have been added to a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a method in the API to return a list of GMarkers or overlays that have been added to a map. You'll have to keep track of them yourself by adding them to a list when they are added to the map.

GMap2 provides [addoverlay removeoverlay and clearoverlays](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2.Events) events that might be useful.